# Flash object covering facebook elements (nav, chat) on Facebook page tab app (Timeline)

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

I have a small facebook welcome page that I am developing for a client, and when I have a youtube player embedded on the page, and the content is scrolled, the flash object covers the top nav bar as well as chat.

[example http://www.selecsosi.com/files/test.png](http://www.selecsosi.com/files/test.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated on methodology for correcting this so that it is rendered behind the wrapper elements.

Comment: Could you provide the embed code you are using please :)

Comment: Figured out my issue, needed to set the wmode to transparent. Thanks for taking a look at the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue, totally stupid on my part. I am using the swfobject library to embed the player and I needed to include in the attribute parameter a wmode : "transparent" for the player.

Comment: Nice you found a solution about your question. If you are fine with this, you have to select your answer as the correct one.